# inserting the Linux shell script file from windows to Linux box using powershell

Tags: linux, powershell, ssh, putty

so i am working on power shell and created the shell script file in C drive now i want to send that file using plink.exe by using power shell to Linux box. 
Tried below commands

```
PS C:\> .\plink.exe -pw  -i "R***t" root@192.168.1.12 ".\adduser.sh"
Unable to open connection:

PS C:\> .\plink.exe -i ssh "R***t" root@192.168.1.12 ".\adduser.sh"

PS C:\> .\plink.exe -i ssh "R***t" -P 22 root@192.168.1.12 ".\adduser.sh"
Unable to open connection:

PS C:\> .\plink.exe -i ssh "R***t" -P 22 root@192.168.1.12 ".\adduser.sh"
Unable to open connection:
```

basically how we can connect to Linux box usin g plink.exe through power shell

> if we need any sshkey let me confirm and how can we generate the ssh
>   key for plink.exe and what are the options need to use for ssh key

so if any valuable suggestions appreciable and thanks in advance.....

Comment: Are you trying to "upload" the `kdump_config.sh` file to the Linux box?

Comment: yep i am trying to upload

Comment: See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42293621/1794706#1794706

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO insert the shell script file from windows machine to Linux box you need to download the "plink" file from internet and keep it in C:\drive and run the command like below

```
PS C:\> .\pscp.exe .\abc.sh root@1.2.3.4.:/root
```

after that you can use the plink to connect the linux box by using below command

```
PS C:\> .\plink.exe -pw "L****e" root@1.2.3.4 -P 22 "ls"
```

> here "-pw" means password and "-P" means port number

Answer (score 1):

[plink](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) is only a command-line interface for putty. Similar to the ssh command in unix/linux. You cannot upload/transfer files using plink.

You can use the [pscp](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp) to do it.

Here's a reference to how you can create SSH keys to connect to your server without using a password.

https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.67/htmldoc/Chapter8.html#pubkey

Answer (score 1):

plink is one tool in the entire suite of Simon Tatham's SSH package called PuTTY.
PuTTY provides SSH capabilities to WIndows users, and it comes with a bunch of compiled command line tools.

Plink is the equivalent of the SSH (secure (remote) shell) command on a linux machine. 
Pscp is the equivalent of the SCP (Secure CoPy) command.
Psftp is the equivalent of SFTP (Secure File Transfer Protocol) which uses the same transfer methods as SCP but with an FTP like comman line interface.
PuTTY itself is a graphical tool that uses the same code as plink to create remote shells or commands over SSH or Telnet protocols (and many more), but it's probably a bit much to go into right now.

From the looks of it, it seems you are trying to get a shell script copied to your Linux server, so you should not be using the command to open a shell, but rather use the command to do a secure copy.

In short, use PSCP, not PLINK. (and maybe read the manual on it, so you get the arguments right)

Answer (score 0):

I have briefly tried "Post-SSH" third-party module to Powershell, and it looks quite good. :)
`Find-module Posh-SSH`

`Find-module Posh-SSH | Install-module`

After that you can

`$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName "1.2.3.4" -Credential (Get-Credential)
Invoke-SSHCommand -Session $session -Command 'ls -l'`

And finally close the session again

`$session | Remove-SSHSession`

http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2016/04/using-ssh-with-powershell/

Comment: i need to use plink only